# Invalid argument name: Argument names must not be quoted

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

To configure NSG rules, I am trying to use For_Each rule with local block with `each key` and `each value`.
While declaring the numerical value under local, I am getting below error :-

Checked and the format seems to be right, still getting the same error.
Code :-

```
#Web tier subnet NSG rule
  ##local block for security rules
 locals {
   App_Inbound_Layer7Port_Map{
    "990" = "80"
    "1000": "443"
   }
```

Error :-

```
PS C:\Terraform> terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Unexpected "App_Inbound_Layer7Port_Map" block
│ 
│   on c6-04-appsubnet-andNSG.tf line 24, in locals:
│   24:    App_Inbound_Layer7Port_Map{ 
│
│ Blocks are not allowed here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid argument name
│
│   on c6-04-appsubnet-andNSG.tf line 25, in locals:
│   25:     "1000": "443",
│
│ Argument names must not be quoted.
```

Comment: you are missing an `=`  your map, it should be    `App_Inbound_Layer7Port_Map = {`

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are declared as key-value, not as blocks. In your code you are declaring `App_Inbound_Layer7Port_Map` as a block.

Here is how it should be:

```
locals {
   App_Inbound_Layer7Port_Map = {
       "990": "80"
       "1000": "443"
   }
}
```